# Error: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this error: exit code 1 when trying to build my project.

As a debugging measure, I went to my Console > All Messages and tried to build my project and this was output:

[image]

Any idea what this error could mean?

I have cleaned my project, deleted all derived data, and updated my Pods in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- You should check two classes with same name added in your Xcode project or Isn't you import .m file